# 32 bit Linux kernel in Android system: need 64 bit timestamp in microseconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, android-kernel

i need to get timestamp value in 64 bit in microseconds in the linux kernel of the android system which is a 32bit system

is there s direct kernel exported function call to achieve it ?

i saw jiffies for 64 bit and there are function which convert the 64bit jiffies to nano seconds. jiffies_64_to_clock_t();

any pointer to go forward will be helpful to get me the 64 bit timestamp in microseconds

thanks for helping

Comment: So something like [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)?

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and consider using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Comment: gettimeofdate and clock_gettime will return 32 bit size, i need it in 64 bit in microseconds, in the 32 bit linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel timestamps are in nanoseconds.
You can use `getnstimeofday()`, `ktime_get_ns()`, or `getrawmonotonic()` to get a `struct timespec`, or `ktime_get_real()` or `ktime_get()` to get a `ktime_t`; the latter can be converted into a 64-bit nanoseconds counter with `ktime_to_ns()`.

Comment: all these give the values in 32 bit variable size, i am looking for a variable sixe of 64bit

Comment: Read again the last part of the answer.

Comment: yes i saw the last part, but as told i needed the timestamp in 64 bit  variable and that too in microseconds, if i get it with nano, after if divide by 1000,then i will loose the last 3 digits and it will reduce the total count i can do with 64 bit variable if it was in  micro seconds right ?

Comment: Yes, it will reduce the total count. To about 500 years.

Comment: 2 ^ 64 = 18446744073709551616 = 7014.6543 months = 584.5545 years
2 ^ 63 =  9223372036854775808 = 3507.3271 months = 292.2772 years



2 ^ 63/1000( to get micro seconds) = 9223372036854775808/1000 = 9223372036854775.808 in micro  = 3507.3271 months = 292.2772 years ; i think this i good enough